# Permissions for List or Library Columns

Tags: list, permissions, column, form, library

Is there any way to give permission to a specific field of a list or library? I want one of my users for example cannot add or edit data in a specific column.
Can I set permissions to the form and its fields??

Comment: There exist third party solutions though, such as SharePointBoost PermissionBoost. I'm not sure about promoting commercial products on this page so I'm adding this as a comment this time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hy,
You can do that in Infopath, not directly in a site or Designer
and in infopath just try to manupilate rules its pretty easy ;)

Good luck

Comment: Can you help me on this? How can I assign permissions to my Infopath forms?

Answer (score 2):

A workaround for this is to create a lookup field that points to a list where only some users have access too.

It works, but it is kind of a hack...

Answer (score 1):

No, it is impossible. You can do it through customization of sharepoint forms.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at column level.
You can assign permission to particular Item.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with the native sharepoint's feature.
If you want you can find some feature, in codeplex, like this: http://sptoolbasket.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SharePoint%20-%20List%20Columns%20Manager

Comment: this one too: https://sppex.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Assigning permissions at the column level is not possible. My workaround: Create a calculated column (for example "Column001_copy") and give it the formula: "=[Column001]". Display this column in the list view for your user instead of the editable column.

Answer (score 0):

Should this field be editable to SPGroupA and not editable to SPGroupB?
You can use javascript scom to find the SP group that the current user belongs to :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122139/check-if-current-users-belongs-to-sp-group-using-javascript-client-side-object-m

And then make the field read-only :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362153/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-make-an-input-readonly